# Is "conservativism" a word?

Tags: word-choice, is-it-a-word, diction

I know that "conservatism" is the more commonly used term, but is "conservativism" a less preferred, but legitimate word, or just a misspelling?

www.dictionary.com has "conservativism", but I'm not sure I view them as a credible source.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Merriam-Webster [does not list](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/conservativism) *conservativism*, but Wiktionary [does](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/conservativism):

> **conservativism**
>
> 1. Alternative form of *conservatism*.

*Conservativism* is surely not a typo (as, say, *consrvetism* would be). It is legitimately formed from the adjective *conservative* and the suffix *-ism*. However, as you say yourself, *conservatism* is the much more commonly used term. The [British National Corpus](http://www.natcorp.ox.ac.uk/) has 474 cites for *conservatism*, but only 3 for *conservativism*.

That being said, there are languages (e.g. German) in which the equivalent of *conservativism* (*Konservativismus*) is pretty much as common as the equivalent of *conservatism* (*Konservatismus*).

Comment: Just to add to your answer: the OED lists this as an alternative spelling: http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/39572#eid8588960, although it records conservatism as being the older word.

Comment: I think OED beats wiktionary - suggest the answer be updated as @jascol suggests.

Answer (score -1):

[Merriam-Webster does not contain *conservativism*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/conservativism), and I'd say that's a pretty credible source.

Comment: OED does, and I'd say that's a pretty credible source.

Comment: The fact that a dictionary does not list some word should never be taken as some kind of claim by the dictionary-makers that said word does not exist.

Answer (score -2):

I agree with the post that says that conservatism is a newer development.  Whenever I hear it it grates on my ears.   I would go with the OED every time.

Comment: I'm confused. If you would "go with the OED every time," then why don't you believe the OED when it says that *conservatism* appears to be slightly older than *conservativism*? Did you make a typo?

Answer (score -4):

The English dictionary in Microsoft's 2013 Office suite does not question conservativism.

Comment: It's good to know that Microsoft does not question conservativism.

Comment: I don't think that is an authoritative source on this site.

Comment: No offense @robocliff but I think this source is even less reputable than the questioned-by-OP dictionary.com!